# Prolog, how to order a list with constraints

Tags: prolog, constraint-programming

I am quite new with Prolog and I am trying to use it to order a list with defined constraints.

The problem starts with the following definitions:

- An `Item` is length 3 list: `[Name, Type, Weight]`.
- An `Content` is a list of Items `[item_0,.....item_n]`.
- A  `ContentList` is a list of `Content`

For example:

With the items:

```
item_1 = [chicken, meat, 1.0]
item_2 = [eggplant, vegetable, 0.5]
item_3 = [tomatoes, vegetable, 1.0]
item_4 = [bread, other, 0.2]
```

We build two Contents:

```
contentA = [item_2, item_3]
contentB = [item_1, item_4]
contentC = [item_3, item_4]
```

So now, let's say we have some content defintions:

```
hasItemType([_, XType, _], XType).

hasListItemType([H|T], Type) :-
    hasItemType(H, Type);
    hasListItemType(T, Type).

hasListOnlyItemType([H|T], Type) :-
    hasItemType(H, Type),
    hasListItemType(T, Type)

isVegetarian(Content) :- hasListOnlyItemType(Content, vegetable).
hasVegetables(Content) :- hasListItemType(Content, vegetable).
hasMeat(Content) :- hasListItemType(Content, meat).
```

The goal would be:

Given a list of `Content` returns a  `ContentList` that matches the best a defined order:

For example (but thus my question i'm not sure if it is the right way of doing it.)

```
 -> `order(A, B)` A is before B in the output list.


order(ContentA, ContentB) :-
    isVegetarian(ContentA),
    hasVegetables(ContentB).

order(ContentA, ContentB) :-
    hasVegetables(ContentA),
    hasMeat(ContentB).
```

Ideally, I would like something like that:

`solve([contentB, contentC, contentA])` to would return `[contentA, contentB, contentC]`

because:
    order(contentA, contentB), order(contentA, contentC), order(contentB, contentC)

So I have basically two questions:

1. Is it a reasonable way to formalise my problem.
2. Once the `order` and constraints are correctly defined, what would be the way to write a solver?

I understand my question is a bit wide, so I will take any suggestions, references, ideas ;)

Thanks in advance if you read this!

Comment: Where is  hasItemType(H, Type) definition?? also provide a simple example  for order/2 output  and  an example for solver.

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking at my question. I have added a bit of details. That's actually my question, I'm not sure on how to write the solver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a sorting function but not sorting with standard comparing functions-predicates like `=<` or `>=` but with using your order predicate. So you need to implement a sorting algorithm in Prolog, for example  insertion sort:

```
insertionSort([], []).

insertionSort([HEAD|TAIL], RESULT) :-
   insertionSort(TAIL, LIST), insertInPlace(HEAD, LIST, RESULT).

insertInPlace(ELEMENT, [], [ELEMENT]).

insertInPlace(ELEMENT, [HEAD|TAIL], [ELEMENT|LIST]) :-
   order(ELEMENT,HEAD), insertInPlace(HEAD, TAIL, LIST).

insertInPlace(ELEMENT, [HEAD|TAIL], [HEAD|LIST]) :-
   \+order(ELEMENT ,HEAD), insertInPlace(ELEMENT, TAIL, LIST).
```

You could also implement mergesort which is more efficient. Since I have no data I can't see if the above is really working or if it has some bugs so I'm waiting for comments...

I think it works I tested it by querying:

```
insertionSort([[[chicken, meat, 1.0],[beaf, meat, 1.0]],[[eggplant, vegetable, 0.5],[tomatoes, vegetable, 1.0]]],Result).
```

where I gave a list [content1,cntent2] where content1 had type meat and content 2 had type vegetable so according to order predicate the output should be [content2,content1] so the output I think is right:

```
?- insertionSort([[[chicken, meat, 1.0],[beaf, meat, 1.0]],[[eggplant, vegetable, 0.5],[tomatoes, vegetable, 1.0]]],Result).
Result = [[[eggplant, vegetable, 0.5], [tomatoes, vegetable, 1.0]], [[chicken, meat, 1.0], [beaf, meat, 1.0]]] ;
false.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great starting point. I will try and share with you where i go with it.

Comment: I tried with different examples and it seems to work very well! Thank very much. The process of building Prolog programs is now clear! Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad that helped!!, keep in mind that your problem was more like to understand that you need a sorting algorithm, then you could implement any sorting algorithm you wish ,e.g you could implement merge sort which is even more efficient ....